# How to get the date info right aligned correctly inline with the name info?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, datetime

I want the date info to come inline with my name  and produce a pdf similar to [image]

I used the following code

This results in slight offset on the date display( I wonder why the date is displayed above name).
Can anyone help me to align this inline with name?

```
\documentclass[margin,line,a4paper,11pt]{resume}
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Divya K S)
   /Title  (Divya's Resume)
   %/   CreationDate (D:20040502195600)
   /Subject (Resume)
   /Keywords (Divya, Resume)
}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    
\begin{document}
\name{\Large Divya K S}
\begin{flushright}
    \today
\end{flushright}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

resume. cls file can be found
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OhGcmRPzHKPvFserZmEjrkfQWFpS1vQS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please provide a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.  We don't have enough information with the snippet you've included.

Comment: Added the extra code

Comment: Where can we find `resume.cls`?

Comment: Added the file loc in description

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear in what context this is used, e.g. what causes the line below the text. But something like this might work (again, depending on context).

```
\name{{\Large Divya K S}\hfill \today}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this causing the text to go out of page border

Comment: I don't have the `resume` class, so I can't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bandage solution to the prob. Let me know if there is a better way to do this:

Updated code snippet from resume.cls

```
\def\namefont{\large\bf}
\def\@linename{\begingroup
\def\\{, }
{\namefont\@name}
**\hspace{0.9\linewidth}\today**
\vskip 2pt
\fullline
\vskip 2pt
```